# .NET library for processing HTML e-mails & stripping previous responses

Tags: c#, .net, html, email

Does anyone know of a .NET library that will process HTML e-mails and can be used to trim out the reply-chain?  It needs to be able to accept HTML -or- text mails and then trim out everything but the actual response, removing the trail of messages that are not original content.  I don't expect it to be able to handle responseswhen they're interleaved into the previous mail ("responses in-line") - that case can fail.

We have a home-built one based on SgmlReader and a series of XSL transforms, but it requires constant maintenance to deal with new e-mail clients.  I'd like to find one I can buy... :)

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: What do you plan to do if someone has altered the previous responses in a different font to make their changes obvious?   If someone sends me 10 questions, I'll add my answers BELOW their questions in their original email.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer much of your question, but the W3C's [Converting HTML to Other Formats](http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html) has a section on converting HTML to text. I hope it helps someone develop a full answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

One free and very useful library we've used for dealing with HTML, including malformed HTML, is the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

There is no StripOutPreviousResponses() function, but it may help you with your home-made one.

Comment: Thanks, Judah. We currently use the SgmlReader code which might be an ancestor of HtmlAgilityPack. I'd love to move to a supported library.

Unfortunately it's the recognition of HTML intent that's our main problem here, rather than the manipulation of the HTML itself. But I appreciate the answer!